# @Output and @HostListener click causes Maximum call stack size exceeded when named the same

Tags: javascript, angular

When having an `@Output` named `click`, and having a `@HostListener` listening for `click`, is it possible to make it so that a **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error doesn't occur? I would like to keep the output value as click, as I already know that I can just rename the output name and it will work.

I have tried `e.stopPropagation()`, but that just gives me an error saying that `stopPropagation` is not a function.

I have a component that looks like this. It has an incoming click listener and an outgoing click emitter:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-button',
  template: `
    <button>{{label}}</button>
  `
})
export class Button {
  @Input() label = '';
  @Input() uri?: string;
  @Output('click') onButtonClick = new EventEmitter<string>();

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick() {
    if (this.uri) {
      this.onButtonClick.emit(this.uri);
    }
  }
}
```

I am then using it like this:

```html
<my-button label="Google" uri="http://google.com" (click)="doSomething()"></my-button>
```

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctqunn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition like:

```
@HostListener("click", ['$event'])
onClick(e) {
  if (this.uri && e !== this.uri) {
    this.onButtonClick.emit(this.uri);
  }
}
```

It will be still emitted twice and you need to handle it in your parent component.

Another way is to remove

```
@Output('click') onButtonClick = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

and pass data through `event` object:

```
@HostListener("click", ['$event'])
onClick(e) {
  if (this.uri) {
    e.data = this.uri;
  }
}
```

**parent.html**

```
(click)="doSomething($event)"
```

**parent.ts**

```
doSomething(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iio1jy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**